# HTML full screen background image

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm not sure whether there is a bug in the newly released Firefox 35.0 or whether there is a problem with my code, however behind a web application I have been using the following to set a high-resolution (cached) background image behind the user interface. From today after upgrading to Firefox 35.0 this no longer works properly - the background image only loads approximately 5-10% down the page from the top and then the background below is a solid #000000. If I load the same code from a computer where Firefox hasn't been upgraded it works perfectly, and in IE it works well too.

```css
/* This is the important part */
img.background-image {
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* This just to give some example context */
div#container {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 600px;
}

div#canvas {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img class="background-image" 
       src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg" alt="" />
  <div id="canvas">
     Web Application is here
  </div>
</div>
```

Please can you advise if there is a way I can achieve this so that it works properly with Firefox and IE, all the most recent versions, or if I should leave it alone and hope Firefox will release another rapid bug fix?! Thank you.

*Note: the background image specified here is just an example I found from Google Images just for this question snippet to work and not the real one used for the web application.*

Comment: why are u using an actual `<img>` tag for fullscreen background image instead of ... u know ... a `background-img`? CSS-only with `background-size:cover;` would make this a lot easier.

Comment: The web application was written when CSS v2 was the standard and adoption of CSS v3 was between minimal and non-existant. I've not personally seen this v3 additional option for cover before but I like it and it works very well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `CSS` to the `html` element and get rid of the `img` tag.

```
html{

     background-size:cover;
     background-image:url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg);
}
```

In case you're wondering why `html` instead of `body`, check [this article](http://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/).

`body` will seem to work, but, as mentioned in a comment to this answer, `html` is always guaranteed to be at least the height of the window, which won't lead to unexpected behaviour.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issues with FireFox 35.0 when using large images.

After pulling my hair out for two days, it appears this issue has been fixed in FireFox 36.0 Beta.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1122845

A very simple test case to show the problem is as follows:

```
var img = new Image();
img.style.position = 'fixed';               
document.body.appendChild(img);                    
img.src = "path/to/a/large/image.jpg";
```

That is just one way in which the problem manifests itself.

Only a small portion of the image will appear. The images don't even need to be massive e.g 200kb will cause problems.

Note: if you're using an existing image on your server to test this, clear the FireFox 35.0 cache first.

Comment: Thanks for adding this info, I'm obviously not going crazy!

Answer (score -1):

put the background on the body tag like this

```
body {
background-image(url) ; 
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately would not give a full-screen background image scaled, but would use the image in it's original dimensions and tile it. The solution needs to work for all desktop screen sizes.

Comment: you just need to add background-size : cover